# XML get Item ID without Foreach

Tags: xml, simplexml

How can I directly call `id="url1"` without a foreach?

Like this:

```
echo $item->url1; // Output: http://url1.com
```

This is  code I have:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<url>
    <item id="url1">http://url1.com/</item>
    <item id="url2">http://url2.com/</item>
</url>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);


foreach($xml->item AS $key => $value){
    echo $value['id'].' = "'.$value.'"<br />';
}
?>
```

This is the output from the code I have:

```
url1 = "http://url1.com/"
url2 = "http://url2.com/"
```

Comment: This is easy with XPath. Try searching for questions mentioning that and SimpleXML, and you should find some examples of how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the document using XPath syntax:

```
$value = $rules->xpath('item[@id="url1"]')[0];
```